# django-tagging loaddata error

Tags: django, django-tagging

I'm trying to do a transition from MySQL to SQLite for a small site. [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/) is used for one of the models. For the transition I'm using the **dumpdata** » **loaddata** method.

The **dumpdata** command works fine to export everything from the MySQL database into JSON. When I try to run the **loaddata** command for the SQLite database, I get this error:

```
IntegrityError: column name is not unique
```

I have isolated this error to the tagging app. The loaddata command won't tell me more (the "verbose" and "traceback" settings don't help).

How can I find out what's wrong in the input data (the tags) so I can import it? Or is there another way to do this whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like doing

```
manage.py reset tagging
```

before running the loaddata command solves this problem.